# Adding :class to link_to that has :controller and :method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

The below works, but I'd lie to add a class to it.

```
<%= link_to "Cancel My Subscription", {:controller => :charges, :action => :cancel}, {:method => :post } %>
```

This is not working:

```
<%= link_to "Cancel My Subscription", {:controller => :charges, :action => :cancel}, {:method => :post }, :class => "btn" %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to add a class to a link is as follows:

```
<%= link_to "Cancel My Subscription", { URL_FOR PARAMS HERE }, :controller => 
        :charges, :action => :cancel, :method => :post, :class => "btn" %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the syntax help! This worked for me.